# Cant set the props of a component inside MemoryRouter(Enzyme)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am mounting Users component inside memory router

I want call setProps to change the value of users.

```
const mountComponent = props => mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MemoryRouter>
           <Users {...props}/>
        </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
);

const wrapper = mountComponent({
   users: [],      
});
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: wrapper.setProps({
   children: cloneElement(wrapper.props().children, { agent: agent }),
}); This code didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to [setProps docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/setProps.html) you can call it only on root elementWrapper, which in our case is `<Provider>`.
Personally, I prefer trying to test raw components, without any wrappers.
Something like this:

```
const mountComponent = props => mount(
  <Users {...props} />
);
```

You can pass your Redux-related data as ordinary props here.

Comment: Since my component is a container I have to wrap it inside the provider,const UsersContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
UsersContainer.displayName = 'connect(Users)';

export default UsersContainer;

Comment: But you can(and probably, should) test your non-connected `<Users />` component.
Otherwise you simply won't gain access to `setProps` and `setState` of tested component, because it won't be the root.
Here are some advices from Redux team about writing tests for connected components - https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components